# How to import and point sample asc files on QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, ascii, sampling

I am trying to import .asc data into QGIS. These data are produced by the Stage Project in 2000. I want to import it into QGIS to allow me to point sample various climatic variables, especially temperature from it ([Link to Stage Three Project data description](http://www.esc.cam.ac.uk/research/research-groups/research-projects/stage-three-project/stage-three-project-simulations)).

I can’t import the data. The .asc data are a far longer version of what is show below. They are 300 to 600 pages when opened in Word.

```
sdprecip_cold.ascgcm     v2.0 30k 034
  i  j       JAN       FEB       MAR       APR       MAY       JUN       JUL       AUG       SEP       OCT       NOV       DEC
  1  1     0.032     0.080     0.049     0.078     0.066     0.059     
  3  1     0.054     0.080     0.087     0.059     0.043     0.071      0.034     0.048     0.045     0.065     0.063     0.050
  4  1     0.055     0.051     0.045     0.041     0.050     0.068     0.043     0.034     0.083     0.081     0.055     0.058
  5  1     0.049     0.075     0.030     0.062     0.065     0.122     
0.180     0.154     0.223     0.209     0.128     0.112     0.091
179 90     0.060     0.104     0.126     0.114     0.116     0.154     0.205     0.247     0.267     0.151     0.123     0.087
180 90     0.074     0.117     0.071     0.133     0.123     0.216     0.165     0.268     0.161     0.144     0.119     0.072
```

or

```
grid_warm.asc     v2.0 42k 034
  i  j     grid
  1  1         2
  2  1         2
  3  1         2
  10  1        2
 11  1         2
 12  1         2
178 90         0
179 90         0
180 90         0
```

I tried importing using **Add raster layer** and also **Translate (Convert format)**. I then tried removing the many spaces between the cells and also removing the first line of the data but both did not work. I have ensured my driver is set to AAIGrid.

Comment: Could you describe your data in more detail? I'm missing some sort of coordinates where the precipitation is measured, which is needed for point sampling. Is there some sample data download?

Comment: the full dataset is no longer on the project website but it is all here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r5p3rm44nc9ez3e/AAA8asHoYuBSLOEt-0ROLd3ba?dl=0